# Why does this event keep getting fired?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, infinite-loop

This script checks to see if the the form has been filled in correctly but the `toggle()` function keeps getting fired (at least in FireFox). In the following example "now here" keeps showing up after the form is valid (that is all fields have some text).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function toggle()
        {
            if(document.getElementById('username').value.length > 1 && document.getElementById('pw1').value.length > 1 && document.getElementById('pw2').value.length > 1 && (document.getElementById('pw1').value == document.getElementById('pw2').value))
            {
                alert("now here")
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false
            }
        }
//-->
</scipt>
Username:<input type="text" name='username' id='username' maxlength="30" onkeyup="toggle()"/><br />
        Password:<input type="password" name="pw1" id="pw1" onkeyup="passwordCheck(document.getElementById('pw1'), document.getElementById('pw2')); toggle()"/><br />
        Confirm password:<input type="password" name="pw2" id="pw2" onkeyup="passwordCheck(document.getElementById('pw1'), document.getElementById('pw2')); toggle()"/>
```

I'm woundering why does `onkeyup` keep getting fired? It's as if the user never takes there finger off the key. Is it because `onkeyup` gets screwed up when it tirggers an alert window because the focus changes from the text field to the window and when ok is pressed the focus changes back to the text field?

UPDATE: I [found it here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112298) in Bugzilla. You can [vote for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=112298#vote_112298). It's been reported since late 2001, why has it bean so long and not fixed???

Comment: because its performance is below expectation?

Comment: [Inline event handlers are bad.](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

Comment: What does passwordCheck do? Why not make these tests on submit?

Comment: @thang I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: @jbabey I'll make the JS external as soon as I get it working

Comment: @rontornambe checks to see if the passwords match, this is easier than submitting the form and making them start again if they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FireFox if you press the enter key on an alert window it fires `onKeyUp`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the function to make the submit change from disabled to enabled when the form is correctly filled out. The function should fire every time the `onKeyUp` is called with the all three inputs because you are calling it in all three inputs.

My jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/BhaeG/) only fires the `alert("now here")` when all conditions of the if statement are correct.

Unless I'm really missing something, it seems like it's working as designed.

Comment: That's weird in FireFox it repeatedly pops up "now here" but in IE it works fine.

Comment: Yes weird as I was doing the js fiddle in latest ver FF on mac and works as described. I'll check in other browsers/platforms.

Comment: It's been [reported before](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112298) though it was years ago and I guess it did not get attention.

Comment: Ahh, I missed typed, as I was initially trying this is Chrome. I see the loop in FF, and the bug.

I bet if you move to a framework (jQuery for example) this wouldn't happen.
I wonder if you name the form and call the function that way, as the alert box is apart of the DOM, but not the form element.

Comment: I just tried using a confirm box and that has same bug in FF. Even tried `window.alert` to no avail
http://jsfiddle.net/BhaeG/1/

Comment: Please vote for the bug on bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112298

Comment: ok, using pure JS, you can do this with some minor changes. Take a look at the updated http://jsfiddle.net/BhaeG/2/

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by using onkeydown instead of onkeyup. YMMV.